# Need help with a snippet

Tags: regular-expressions, yasnippet, spacemacs, js2-mode

Can someone help me with this snippet? I found it [here](https://gist.github.com/kiwanami/af52d0ca067ebde2b9f5)

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: jsdoc comment
# key: doc
# --
/**
* $0
`(save-excursion 
(let* ((pos-fun (re-search-forward "\\<function\\s-*(\\([^)]*\\))"))
        (argstr (and pos-fun (match-string 1)))
        (args (and pos-fun (split-string argstr ",\\s-*"))))
    (loop with params = nil
        for arg in args
        for nump = (string-match "s$" arg)
        for param = (if nump (format " * @param {[]} %s - " arg)
                        (format " * @param {} %s - " arg))
        do
        (if (< 0 (length arg))
            (push param params))
        finally return
        (mapconcat 'identity (reverse (cons " * @return " params)) "\n"))))`
*/
```

it creates this:

```
/**
* 
[yas] elisp error: Search failed: "\\<function\\s-*(\\([^)]*\\))"
*/
```

I'm suspecting there's something wrong with the regex

What this snippet suppose to do? It creates js-doc comments as function headers in js2-mode. So code like `function foo(a, bs, c)` should turn into:

```
/**
* @param {} a - 
* @param {[]} bs - 
* @param {} c - 
* @return 
*/
function foo(port, methods, host) {
```

Comment: If you give us some example text of what you expect to find with the proposed search, I bet someone will be able to help.  Otherwise, we are all just guessing as to what you want to find with the search -- e.g., you might be *mistakenly* hoping to search for some text that says "hello-world", or you might be *mistakenly* searching for your mother's maiden name?  The search fails because it finds no match for the regexp going in a forward direction.

Comment: @lawlist this snippet is for creating js-doc comments in js2-mode. it suppose to be looking for string like `function foo (a, b, c) {`. I'll update the question

Comment: There is a full/complete match, so the regexp appears to be good for your situation.  Are you behind -- i.e., to the left of -- `function foo (a, b, c) {` when you execute the snippet?  The snippet searches forward.

Comment: @lawlist The cursor is at the line above 'function'

Comment: The regexp matches `function (a, b, c)`, but not `function foo (a, b, c)`.

Comment: @npostavs... all right, I think I fixed it... just added `\.*` after `s-*`. Thank you!